# deploying metro app on a tablet without using Visual Studio

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have been trying to deploy my metro app from win8 machine to a tablet .
I am able to complete the whole process of creating the package,signing it and deploying using Powershell in the tablet .The tile of the app appears on the start screen
but when I click on the tile the app just shows the splash-screen and crashes.
The deployment worked no for one of my sample apps but it's not working even for some of the MSDN sample apps like the LockScreen Personalization.

Comment: Do you see any crash information in the Event Log?

Comment: where can i get access to the event log

Comment: Do you have the same version of Windows 8 on the development computer and your tablet (Customer Preview or Release Preview)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the "developer licence" on the target computer? This can be done using powershell (but in admin mode)

All information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx

Shortly, you need to run **Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense** from a Powershell in admin mode.

Comment: yes.i did these steps.i think the problem is related to the low computing power of the tablet as it crashes after starting